# Reusing Activity and Fragment objects

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is it possible that an Activity or Fragment object can be reused by Android system after onDestroy() is called?

In other words: is every call for onCreate() for Activity object and respectively onAttach() for Fragment object preceded by calling its constructor?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't do that. Only framework should call methods like onCreate, onAttach etc..
After onDestroy activity should not be used!

[ActvitiyLifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Fragments)

Comment: I haven't written anywhere that I want to use it. I'm asking whether the system can reuse the Activity or Fragment object after calling onDestroy().

Comment: I'm pretty sure it destroys the activity and fragment completely after calling onDestroy on it. Even if it didn't, it would be just marked for the GC to take it, I think.

Comment: No. After onDestroy specific activty/fragment is destroyed so nobody can reuse it.